# Module build failed: Duplicate declaration "Route"

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy tratando de redireccionar a otra pagina con React.js, estoy utilizando *react router dom* y cuando estoy importando *BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route* me aparece un error en la R de Route, y el error que me pone es:

> Failed to compile.
>
> Error in ./src/login.jsx    Module build failed: Duplicate
> declaration "Route"   import './login.css';
>
> 3 | import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
> 4 | import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
> |                                          ^
> 5 | import Inicio  from "./components/inicio";

Answer (score 0):

Como te está indicando el error... Tienes dos declaraciones de `Route` en el mismo archivo (`./src/login.jsx`):

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Inicio from "./components/inicio";
```

Borra la primera y solo deja:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Inicio from "./components/inicio";
```